# Why AngularJS expression is replaced only once in HTML template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angularjs and trying following html template. But angularjs only replace the first {{ fragment.id }} expression in text area with the value. All the other {{ fragment.id }} expressions are left unmodified in generated html code.

```
<div class="input-box" ng-repeat="fragment in project.fragments">
     <textarea id="code-{{ fragment.id }}" class="code-input" ng-model="content">{{ fragment.content }}</textarea>
     <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" style="margin-top:5px;" ng-click="execute({{ fragment.id }})"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i> Run</button>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          applyCodeMirror({{ fragment.id }});
     </script>
     <div id="result-{{ fragment.id }}" ng-model="result"></div>
</div>
```

I also have a another question is it possible to use angularjs expression to generate JavaScript code like I have done above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things (the code above is concerning)

1. Use `ng-model` to bind `$scope` variables to inputs - your textarea becomes: `<textarea id="code-{{ fragment.id }}" class="code-input" ng-model="fragment.content"></textarea>`
2. `{{}}` is used to output Angular `$scope` variables to the view - you would not use `{{}}` in JavaScript code to get Angular variables, so the `<script>{{fragment.id}}</script>` is invalid. If you want to use the Angular `$scope` variables outside Angular (not recommended, but we all have our reasons) - use `angular.element(elem).scope()` to get an instance of the `scope` (where `elem` is an element within the `ng-controller` declaration)
3. Angular directives (like your `ng-click`) do not need `{{}}` to get `$scope` variables - your `ng-click` becomes: `ng-click="execute(fragment.id)"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your suggestions made me to re-think my design and found [ui-codemirror](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror) which can used to achieve things I am trying to do with generated javascript code.